# How to get the the google play developer id using google-api-php-client?

Tags: google-api, google-play, google-api-php-client

I have the following URL: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=. Is there a way to get the "id" of an user using the google-api-php-client, if of course the user grants the permissions?

Comment: any updates on this ?!

Comment: Nope, haven't been able to get an answer to this, I've made the user enter it

Comment: Did you try to contact google about that ? (So that i can upvote that as well )